# Function Overloading in TCL

Tags: tcl, overloading

Are there any packages or any specific way to support function or procedure overloading in TCL??

This is my scenario. I need to write a generic procedure that accepts two or 3 files, wherein I may or may not have the third file (File3)

```
                 proc fun { File1 File2 File3 }
                    {
                    }

                 proc fun { File1 File2 }
                    {
                    }
```

Comment: I realize it's just pseudo-code, but that bracing style will not work in tcl.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no overriding in tcl. The second declaration will just replace the first one.
But you handle it with a single procedure. There are two ways at least:

1) Specify the last argument with its default value. Then it will be optional when you calls the function.

```
proc fun { file1 file2 {file3 ""} } {
  if {$file3 != ""} {
    # the fun was called with 3rd argument
  }
}
```

2) Use the special argument `args`, which will contain all arguments as a list. And then analyze the number of arguments actually passed to.

```
proc fun { args } {
  if {[llength $args] == 3} {
    # the fun was called with 3rd argument
  }
}
```

Comment: Tcl has very good var-args support, but it does mean that overloading is a no-go. The two are antagonistic.

Answer (score 5):

Tcl doesn't really support procedure overloading, which makes sense when you consider that it doesn't really have types, per se. Everything is a string that can, depending on value, be interpreted as other types (int, list, etc).

If you can describe what it is you're trying to accomplish (why you think you need overloading), we might be able to make a recommendation about how to accomplish it.

Given the edit to your question, there's a couple different ways to go about it. GrAnd has shown 2 of them. A third, and one I'm a fan of, is to use information specifically about how the command was called:

```
proc fun { File1 File2 {File3 ""}} {     ;# file3 has a default
    if {[llength [info level 0]] == 3} { ;# we were called with 2 arguments
                                         ;# (proc name is included in [info level 0])
        # do what you need to do if called as [fun 1 2]
    } else {                             ;# called with 3 arguments
        # do what you need to do if called as [fun 1 2 3]
    }
}
```

Comment: A clever trick indeed--I always wondered what to do if there's no sensible default value for an optional argument ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to hack puts, using a namespace to hide puts and `::` to access built-in:

```
namespace eval newNameSpace {
  proc puts {arg} {
    set tx "ADDED:: $arg"
    ::puts $tx 
  }
  puts 102 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, you can do this:

```
proc example {
    -file1:required
    -file1:required
    {-file3 ""}
} {
    if {$file3 ne ""} {
            #Do something ...
    }
}
```

when you call the proc

```
example -fiel1 info -file2 info2
```